# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64 errors for building Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

Im trying to build a unity game in Xcode and when trying to build get an undefined symbol error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEejq.png) with the log message below, not sure what this error means or what is casuing it, im new to using xcode so any advice is appreciated.

Error Log:

Ld /Users/home/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-hgvppjtljvdtqnfwqcnrrczymarg/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework normal (in target 'UnityFramework' from project 'Unity-iPhone')
cd /Users/home/Documents/BWB/Build
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -Xlinker -reproducible -target arm64-apple-ios12.0 -dynamiclib -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS16.4.sdk -L/Users/home/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-hgvppjtljvdtqnfwqcnrrczymarg/Build/Intermediates.noindex/EagerLinkingTBDs/Debug-iphoneos -L/Users/home/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-hgvppjtljvdtqnfwqcnrrczymarg/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -L/Users/home/Documents/BWB/Build/Libraries -F/Users/home/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-hgvppjtljvdtqnfwqcnrrczymarg/Build/Intermediates.noindex/EagerLinkingTBDs/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/home/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-hgvppjtljvdtqnfwqcnrrczymarg/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -filelist /Users/home/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-hgvppjtljvdtqnfwqcnrrczymarg/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Unity-iPhone.build/Debug-iphoneos/UnityFramework.build/Objects-normal/arm64/UnityFramework.LinkFileList -install_name @rpath/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -map -Xlinker /Users/home/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-hgvppjtljvdtqnfwqcnrrczymarg/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Unity-iPhone.build/Debug-iphoneos/UnityFramework.build/UnityFramework-LinkMap-normal-arm64.txt -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/home/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-hgvppjtljvdtqnfwqcnrrczymarg/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Unity-iPhone.build/Debug-iphoneos/UnityFramework.build/Objects-normal/arm64/UnityFramework_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -fembed-bitcode-marker -stdlib=libc++ -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -weak_framework CoreMotion -weak-lSystem -liPhone-lib -framework Metal -framework Security -framework MediaToolbox -framework CoreText -framework AudioToolbox -weak_framework AVFoundation -framework AVKit -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreMedia -weak_framework CoreMotion -framework CoreVideo -framework Foundation -framework OpenAL -framework QuartzCore -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -liconv.2 -lil2cpp /Users/home/Documents/BWB/Build/Libraries/baselib.a -weak_framework GameController -framework Pods_UnityFramework -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/home/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-hgvppjtljvdtqnfwqcnrrczymarg/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Unity-iPhone.build/Debug-iphoneos/UnityFramework.build/Objects-normal/arm64/UnityFramework_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/home/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-hgvppjtljvdtqnfwqcnrrczymarg/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"__GetState", referenced from:
_ICadeNative__GetState_mAB938971777D74B93C1E2A15239AC2FEB08DC421 in Assembly-CSharp__5.o
(maybe you meant: _ICadeNative__GetState_mAB938971777D74B93C1E2A15239AC2FEB08DC421)
"__SetActive", referenced from:
_ICadeNative__SetActive_m79897F564BC2B14CF2B6B3ED9E212280737E588D in Assembly-CSharp__5.o
(maybe you meant: _ObjectPool__SetActive_m18EC8B1009F0695F327067E2CF3C51A738C24535, _ObjectPool__SetActiveAndSendMessages_m07A3BE8F73D37410FF0CC9AFF5B1EDB879F1FEC5 , _ICadeNative__SetActive_m79897F564BC2B14CF2B6B3ED9E212280737E588D )
"__SetStateCallback", referenced from:
_ICadeNative__SetStateCallback_mFE78AD426074280FD56B3E8ADDBBE4BA769CA30C in Assembly-CSharp__5.o
(maybe you meant: _ICadeNative__SetStateCallback_mFE78AD426074280FD56B3E8ADDBBE4BA769CA30C)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

**Pod File:**

Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'
target 'Unity-iPhone' do

## Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks

use_frameworks!

## Pods for Unity-iPhone

target 'Unity-iPhone Tests' do
inherit! :search_paths
# Pods for testing
end

end

target 'UnityFramework' do

## Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks

use_frameworks!

## Pods for UnityFramework

end

Had one small lead that said some ad meadiators can cuase these problems but im not using any advertisement so i cant try removing the packages as they dont exist. The internet has not returned any other suggestions so i am stuck on what to do going forward.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.